# Hide powerpoint notes page numbers

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to write some VBA to hide page numbers on the notes page in PowerPoint. I can do this for the slides using the code below, but cant find a solution for the notes/handouts page.

```
Sub hideNotesPageNumbers()
Dim sld As Slide

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
sld.HeadersFooters.SlideNumber.Visible = False
Next sld
End Sub
```

So Possibly, something like

```
Dim sld As NotesPage

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.NotesPage 
sld.HeadersFooters.NotesPageNumber.Visible = False 
Next sld
```

In powerpoint you can do this via Insert -> Header and Footer -> Note and Handouts -> page numbers
[image: Screenshot of powerpoint userform the hide page numbers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug/design flaw. While this code should work:

```
Sub HideNotesPageNumbers()
    Dim oSlide As Slide

    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        oSlide.NotesPage.HeadersFooters.SlideNumber.Visible = msoFalse
    Next oSlide
End Sub
```

it will only give you an error because the HeaderFooters property has been left out of the object model for notes pages. It appears MS is aware of this, because on the [support page for .NotesPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.notespage?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbapp10.chm531022)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue), they include this disclaimer:

"The following properties and methods will fail if applied to a SlideRange object that represents a notes page: **Copy** method, **Cut** method, **Delete** method, **Duplicate** method, **HeadersFooters** property, **Hyperlinks** property, **Layout** property, **PrintSteps** property, **SlideShowTransition** property."

If it's any help, you can run this code to hide the page numbers on new notes pages. Existing notes pages will still show the number.

```
Sub HideNotesMasterPageNumbers()
    ActivePresentation.NotesMaster.HeadersFooters.SlideNumber.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining the problem